# How to output 'ENTER', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT' keyboard output with Java?

Tags: java, keyboard, key, sensors

I have three buttons that will give value between 0 and 2 if not pressed and between 999 and 1000 if pressed.

I can read it with java and all, but I want to simulate keyboard keys if one of those buttons are pressed.

Is there something like isKeyboardKey(LEFT); that represents a keyboard key in Java?

Example:

```
String key_enter;
String key_left;
String key_right;

if ( sensorValue1 > 100 )
{
key_enter = ENTER; // it will simulate ENTER ( work like regular enter button), so if Word or Notepad is open and the program runs, it will go to new line like a normal ENTER hit.
} else if (sensorValue2 > 100 )
{
key_left = LEFT; // will work like regular left keyboard button
} else if ( sensorValue 3 > 100 )
{
key_right = RIGHT; // will work like regular right keyboard button
} else { System.out.print("No sensor value"); }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to generate keyboard events? Is [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) what you need? Or do you just want your application to treat pressing these buttons as pressing keyboard keys?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

Comment: Yes precisely! Thank you, I will have a look and try to figure out how to use them. Hope someone places an example code, only one small example code is enough and so I can mark it as solved. Anyways thank you for the direction!

Comment: I've got it, Thank you, code works perfectly `try { 
                    Robot robot = new Robot(); 
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
                    } catch (AWTException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using java.awt.Robot

```
            try { 
            Robot robot = new Robot(); 
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
            } catch (AWTException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
```